# How to properly dispose of Bitmaps loaded into Control.BackgroundImage

Tags: c#, bitmap, dispose

So we are trying to tune an application, and all over these ancient Winforms are statements like this in the Designer

```
this.btnCancel.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)resources.GetObject("btnCancel.BackgroundImage")));
```

In places with no controls, loaded bitmaps are part of an ImageList object whose container has disposed called on it when the form closes.  dotMemory thinks there are still many outstanding Bitmaps, so my suspicion is that its these BackgroundImage bitmaps that aren't properly being disposed of.

I can see two options, neither of which I really like.
1) Keep track of all the controls that have background images.  Manually set them all to null in Dispose
2) Loop through every control on the page, if it has a BackgroundImage, set it to null.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I don't know of dotMemory, but are the objects still there if you explicitly call `GC.Collect()`?

Comment: What does dotMemory say about who owns those outstanding references? - they must be rooted somewhere if they are not collected.

Comment: The warning is accurate, Winforms cannot know if the image isn't used anywhere else so doesn't dispose it.  Setting it to null doesn't do anything, calling Dispose() does.  If you don't then the next full GC will get rid of it.

Comment: dotMemory is a JetBrains memory analysis tool. The outstanding objects are tracked back to the resources.GetObject calls in the form the controls are on.  The Controls are being disposed of, but even manually calling GC.Collect still shows a number of Bitmap Byte[] objects and related GPStream ones

Answer (score 0):

There are two different reasonable ways of handling control background images:

1. Every control is given its own background-image object.  The object should be disposed when the control is (possibly in a handler for the control's `Disposed` event).
2. Every control is given a reference to a background image whose lifetime will be that of the application.  Disposing the control should not dispose the image.

Because Microsoft wanted to allow for approach #2, disposing a control does not affect its background image; as a consequence, it's necessary to dispose the image manually (as noted, an event handler is a good way to do that).

Note that fonts have a problem similar to controls, but fonts deal with it differently.  Setting the `Font` property for most controls will cause them to take a snapshot of its font family, size, style, and other characteristics, but will not make them actually use that font object.  Controls can grab the necessary information from a `Font` even if it has been disposed, so controls neither dispose their `Font` nor care if it is disposed.  It might be possible for controls' `BackgroundImage` property to behave somewhat similarly (only use the supplied image once, to a new bitmap which would be privately owned by the control and disposed when the control is) but copying image data to a bitmap is more expensive than copying font family, size, etc. to a new `Font` object.

Comment: So it seems that rather than try to make this code actually dispose background images, I may be better off changing the initialization?  Instead of the current one line, load the resource to an object that's life is that of the application and check each form initialization to see if it exists before loading it

Comment: @ItinerantEngineer: That can be a good approach in cases where it makes sense.  If most of the images will have a reasonable likelihood of being used throughout the lifetime of the application, creating them once and using them forever may be better than trying to have them be loaded only when they're visible.  Such an approach may be totally unsuitable for things like dynamically-generated images, however, which may quickly become obsolete.